# Login failed for user ‘NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON’ in BCS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, bcs, external-list

I have already configured BSC service in SharePoint 2013, I created an external content type in SharePoint Designer, everything is ok.

But unfortunately, When I tried to browse an external list from the browser.

I got

> Login failed for user ‘NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON’

I tried to check this stack exchange thread

[SharePoint Business Connectivity Services (BCS) Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45811/sharepoint-business-connectivity-services-bcs-login-failed-for-user-nt-author)

but it's not helped me! Any help I will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem might occur because of the connections authentication mode is not assigned to **BDC Identity**.

- Below Connection properties -> Select Client  -> Below Secure Store Application ID -> Select BDC Identity.

For more details you can check [Login failed for user ‘NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON’ in SharePoint Business Connectivity Service](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/10/10/login-failed-for-user-nt-authorityanonymous-logon-in-sharepoint-2010-bcs/)

Comment: open SharePoint designer > external content type > check the connections. also open the link that should instruct you

Comment: Please don't forget to up vote and make it as answer if it helps you